# List with Streams java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of objects called **List  persons**

```
public class Person{

        private String name;
        private String lastname;
        private String birthday;
        private String address;

  //constructor and Getters and Setters ommited....

}
```

And I need to have another list of all the birthday registers of this list.
I would know how can I do this birthdayList with Streams with JAVA8

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and collect, they are basic stream operations.

```
personList.stream()
     .map(Person::getBirthday)
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```